# require errors show private instead of actual file path

Tags: node.js

Today I got surprised by the following (you can try at node repl):

```
require("/tmp/bad.json")
SyntaxError: /private/tmp/bad.json: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 3
```

As you can see, I required (intentionally) a JSON file that contains a syntax error. However, on the error message, instead of the actual file path, which starts at '/tmp/' you can see that it has been replaced by the string `/private/`.

Why is this?
I'm using node v8.15.0

Comment: do you have a [`NODE_PATH`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) set?

Comment: No, I don't have any env like that setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Node or the node version but with the operating system. In this case, I was using OSX, where `/tmp` is just a symbolic link to `/private/tmp`. Then when the error was triggered the actual path is showing.